# How to hide a download link from a download manager in PHP

Tags: php, url, download

In PHP, we can do something like

```
<?php
 header("Location: https://www.example.com/test.exe");
?>
```

to download a file. However, the URL will be visible in a download manager such as DAP. So is there really a way to hide the download URL altogether?

Comment: Generate a random string, make a link with the database (string -> file on machine), when the user requests a file, the link is generated, then when it's used, the link is then removed.

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will help you

<?php
$fullpath = 'https://www.example.com/test.exe';
$filename ='test.exe';
header("Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate");
header("Content-Type: application/exe");
header("Content-Length: " .(string)(filesize($fullpath)) );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');                 
readfile($fullpath);
?>
```

MIME type informations

http://filext.com/file-extension/EXE

Comment: I tried it in my Chrome browser. An error message pops up, saying: "Duplicate headers received from the server".